# Passing a NavLink to a Material UI component via the containerElement prop gives “Failed prop type” warning

Tags: reactjs, react-router, material-ui

```
<RaisedButton containerElement={NavLink} to="/somewhere">
   Somewhere
</RaisedButton>
```

Produces the following warning:

```
Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `containerElement` supplied to `RaisedButton`.
in RaisedButton (at App.js:11)
in App (at index.js:23)
in Provider (at index.js:22)
in MuiThemeProvider (at index.js:21)
```

but the Navlink properly renders and redirects to `/somewhere` on click. If this is a deprecated prop that still works then I haven't been able to find what the new prop is called... Please advise. If nothing else I'd like to hide the warning (how?).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to give it the markup for the `containerElement`, something like this (rather than just the name of the element)

```
containerElement={<NavLink to="/home" />}
```

Give that a try and see if it works

Answer (score 26):

As of Material UI 1.0 the prop is called `component`:

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import Button from 'material-ui/Button';

<Button component={Link} to="/open-collective">
  Link
</Button>
```

More about [Buttons](https://material-ui-next.com/demos/buttons/).

**Update:**

From Material UI v4 you may need to use `forwardRef` and wrap `Link` into a `div`:

```
const LinkRef = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => <div ref={ref}><Link {...props} /></div>)

<Button component={LinkRef} to="/open-collective">
  Link
</Button>
```

More [here](https://material-ui.com/guides/composition/#caveat-with-refs).

Comment: this solution breaks the styling of the button

Comment: This doesnt work with MUI5

Answer (score 3):

The easiest solution is to put IconButton inside the Navlink, so whenever you click on the Iconbutton the NavLink is automatically clicked.

Here is a sample of the code:

```
<NavLink to="/" style={{ textDecoration: "none" }}>
  <IconButton>
    <Typography>Home</Typography>
  </IconButton>
</NavLink>
```